# Rails, how create alias of some model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, models

class Migrator

```
       def self.migrate_old_categories
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:data_center_v2)
        ActiveRecord::Base.table_name = "categories"
      end

end
```

I need use it, as i used it always. For example: Category.find(:all)
So, how i can it, when i'm write: Migrator.migrate_old_categories, end script find all Categories?

Thanx, apoligize for my english. Russian.

Answer (score 0):

you can create some model just before your migration

```
class Category < AR
end

class Categories < AR
  def table_name
    "categories"
  end
end
```

After you can do

```
Category.all
```

and

```
Categories.all
```

Comment: Yes, i know. But in this class i need to use many models.
In this class i have 8 methods with different models.
I need create model in current method.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Category  < ActiveRecord::Base
def self.table_name() "categories" end
end
```